# How do I add a .pfx file to Postman?

Tags: api, authentication, postman, client-certificates, pfx

I am testing an API and I was given a .pfx file which contains the Client Certificate (I was also given the password). I am new to APIs and Postman so I would like to know how to add the certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Latest Postman versions support adding PFX file:

from `Settings` → `Certificates` → `Add Certificate`.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to find information about that and all other Postman features on the learning center:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/certificates/

Comment: Hi Danny, thank you for your response. I have had a look at the page you suggested however it states that Postman does not support pfx files. But I have the lates Postman application and it does have an option to include a pfx file

Comment: The pages are in the process of getting updated so there will be _some things_ that might be slightly out of date.   Could you raise an issue on the docs repo so that we can get that sorted. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-docs/issues

Comment: Hi Danny, thank you for your comment I have raised the issue. Can you help me with my problem or redirect me to an appropriate resource? Thanks